# R - Missing values in new created list in a for-loop

Tags: r, list, function, for-loop

I'm trying to write a blackjack-code in R. Since I'm new to this language I'm facing some difficulties. I already wrote two different functions to distribute the first 2 cards to each player and count the total points for each one. Now I want to write a function that's based on the results of the second function to decide if a player has to take another card or not with some conditions. Here's the code:

```
    bj_add_card <-  function(hand) {

      hand <- bj_simplified(hand)
      m_hand <- matrix(unlist(hand), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
      sums <- m_hand[,3]
      sum_players <- as.vector(as.numeric(sums[-1]))
      sum_dealer <- as.numeric(tail(sums), 1)
      add_card <- vector("list")

      for (i in seq_along(sum_players)) {
        if(sum_players[i] <= 11) {
          add_card[i] <- sample(Spielkarten, 1)
        }
        else if(sum_players[i] >= 17) {
          add_card[i] <- "stay"
        }
        else if(11 > sum_players[i] && sum_players[i] < 17) {     
           if(sum_players[i] == 12 && sum_dealer == 4 || 5 || 6) {
           add_card[i] <- "stay"
           }
           else if(sum_players[i] == 12 && sum_dealer != 4 || 5 || 6) {
              add_card[i] <- sample(Spielkarten, 1)
           }
           else if(sum_players[i] == 13 || 14 || 15 || 16 && sum_dealer == 
                    2||3||4||5||6||7||8||9||10) {
              add_card[i] <- "stay"
           }
           else if(sum_players[i] == 13 || 14 || 15 || 16 && sum_dealer != 
                    2||3||4||5||6||7||8||9||10) {
              add_card[i] <- sample(Spielkarten, 1)
           }
       }
     }

     return(add_card)
    }


    bj_add_card(6)
```

I really don't see the problem. Everytime I call this function the output is a list (as it should be) with different amount of arguments, but it does not always match the input number, although it should.  Sometimes it gives me "NULL" as output without any reason. I think it's an overwriting problem but I cannot figure out where the problem is.  Any ideas?

Comment: Don't know if this will solve it but try with `add_card <- list()` and use the double brackets when assigning like `add_card[[i]] <-`

Comment: I suggest trying to boil this down to a much smaller example problem: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).  There are a couple problems I see, and they might not be related to your question (for example, `sum_players[i] == 13 || 14 || 15 || 16` is equivalent to `sum_players[i] == TRUE`).  One thing we definitely need is all the data to run your code, included `bj_simplified` and `Spielkarten`.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. To RLave: I already tried what you said and some other things as storing add_card as list/matrix ecc. but none of this worked. To @NathanWerth: I couldn't post the complete code, because it was too long. bj_simplified is just a function that sums up the two cards for each player, its output is a list with 3 values per lit element (2 cards + the sum of this cards). Spielkarten is a simple vector containing the cards. I would appreciate it if you could explain what kind of problems do you exactly see and why are they a problem. Thank you and I try to boil it down